# Querying DynamoDB not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table `customer_contacts`, with `customer_id` as partition key and `id` as a sort key.

[image: Table]

I want to fetch all records with particular `customer_id` from a lambda, so far I have this

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
const dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

// handler and stuff <..>
payload = {
    TableName : "customer_contacts",
    KeyConditionExpression : "customer_id = :customerId",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {":customerId" : event.pathParameters.id}
}

dynamo.query(payload, callback);
```

I also tried `ExpressionAttributeValues : {":customerId" : {"N": event.pathParameters.id}}`.

`event.pathParameters.id` is 1, I have checked that.
It returns an empty array

```
{
  "Items": [],
  "Count": 0,
  "ScannedCount": 2
}
```

halp

Comment: Are you using any REST framework ? If yes, could you please show that code ... The above payload looks ok

Comment: not using any rest framework. I have a lambda with the role that lets it access the table, if I scan it I get all the records

Comment: Actually I don't know if I am, new to AWS, so I just took the blueprint for accesing DynamoDB and now am tinkering with it @notionquest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to convert `event.pathParameters.id` to number
`Number(event.pathParameters.id)`.